# What is the keyboard shortcut for changing a markup cell to a code cell?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter, jupyter-lab

I can change a code cell to markdown by pressing <kbd>Esc</kbd> then <kbd>m</kbd>. But how do I change it back to a code cell using the keyboard?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The shortcut you need is <kbd>Esc</kbd> and <kbd>Y</kbd>.

Use <kbd>Esc</kbd> and <kbd>H</kbd> to get a list of all shortcuts.

Comment: @EmmanuelGoldstein Press Ctrl+A to select all cells and then Esc and M to change them to markdown